# Change empty string to "Nostring" when reading from a file

Tags: string, matlab

I want to read from a text file which has certain blank string cells in it. However, the character data isn't a numeric value, so I cannot use
'emptyvalue',NaN.
Is there a similar way for textread to fill blank cells for string with 'Nostring'?
I have tried many methods to overcome this but I am still lost. I have read that using 
"%[^ ]" can ignore characters in the box but I get an error when using it. Am I using it the wrong way?

```
inFile = 'filepath';

 % Extracting data from the input file
 [a,b,c,d] = textread(inFile,'%*d %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %f %f %*d %[^ ] %s','headerlines',2,'delimiter','\t','emptyvalue', NaN);
```